# Add all numbers (in a while loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

so Im practicing coding in python. My question is this "So I make program that add all the number that enter by a user but the output of the program is not the sum of all the numbers that the user enter.
[image: This is my code, I don't know why stackoverflow denied to enter my image.]

Comment: [Please do not post code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi don't include your code as an image. Include it as text. Paste it in, then highlight it and click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: `sum_num = num + num` should be `sum_num = sum_num + num` or `sum_num += num`

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first sum_num need a initial value

```py
sum_num = 0
```

and, change sum_num in loop every time is needed:

```py
sum_num = sum_num + num
```

all code based at yours:

```py
    i = 0
    sum_num = 0
    while 1 == 1:
        num = int(input('enter a number :'))
        sum_num = sum_num + num
        i = i + 1
        if i > 5:
            print('Total number is :' + str(sum_num))
            break
```

if it's helpful , pls accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the same job by another code**
**if you have the count of the numbers that user will enter you can use this code :**

```
#create a variable that store the total value
sum_num = 0

#for loop take a the number in range to repeat the code by it
for i in range(5):

    #take the number from user and store it
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    #add the number to total variable
    sum_num += num

#at the end of the loop print the total
print("Total Number Is " + str(sum_num))
```

**If you don't have the count of number that user will enter Use This Way :**

```
#create a variable that store the total value
sum_num = 0

#create flag that tell me if user won't enter any other numbers or he want to
#enter more numbers
flag = True

#while loop take a flag and will be in the loop while flag is true
while(flag):

    #take the number from user and store it
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    #add the number to total variable
    sum_num += num

    #ask user if he want to continue
    ask = input("Do you want to continue : ")
    if(ask.lower() == 'no' or ask.lower() == 'n') :
    flag = False

#at the end of the loop print the total
print("Total Number Is " + str(sum_num))
```